# Imprimir datos de una consulta UNION SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta a dos tablas con `UNION`. El problema es que al intentar imprimir cualquier dato de la 2ª consulta me dice *undefine X-campo*, pero la de la primera consulta sí me imprime datos.

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php
  $query=mysqli_query($conexion,

    "SELECT de,para,nombre,apellido,fecha,avatar,post_id FROM comentarios 
       WHERE para='$id'
       UNION ALL
      SELECT de,para,nombre_e,apellido_e,fecha_e,avatar_e,id_post FROM notificaciones
     WHERE para='$id'
     ORDER BY GREATEST(fecha,fecha )DESC");
```

Luego imprimo datos con el `while`:

```
if ($query) {
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

      echo $row["nombre"];//imrprime nombre de la primera consulta sussccefully
      echo $row["nombre_e"];//me dice undefined index nombre_e
   }
}
```

No entiendo por qué o a qué se debe el error.

gracias @OscarGarcia por entender mi problema y lo que intento hacer **la tipica campanita con un sistema de notificaciones** por lo tanto tratar de mostrar dos tablas en un mismo contenido ordenada por fecha para las notificaciones de comentarios y evaluciones estoy seguro que esto me servira como guia en un futuro ya que es uno de los codigos que he tenido mas problemas **mostrar dos tablas juntas en orden de fecha**, volviendo al tema tu codigo me dio los siguientes resultados..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con el primer fragmento de codigo funciona pero me salen contenido en blanco osea vacio y me lo muestra tal cual no se a que se debe y con el segundo fragmento de codigo me sale lo mismo undefined index X-campo
gracias por tomarte la molestia de ayudarme espero y puedas seguir ayudandome y aclararme estas dudas

Comment: Podrías explicarnos que intentas hacer? Tal vez una SQL union no sea necesaria y con un join sea suficiente

Comment: Lo que intentas hacer no tiene sentido porque un UNION agrega filas a tu resultado, manteniendo el nombre inicial de los campos. ¿No querrás hacer un JOIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una unión agrega registros a una consulta manteniendo el nombre inicial de los campos (y, como requisito adicional, debe tener el mismo número de campos), por lo que los datos de la segunda consulta "se fundirán" con el nombre de los campos de la primera, compartiendo nombre de la siguiente manera:

```
notificaciones.de         => comentarios.de       => de
notificaciones.nombre_e   => comentarios.nombre   => nombre
notificaciones.apellido_e => comentarios.apellido => apellido
etc...
```

Por lo que no notarás diferencia entre los registros obtenidos de la tabla  `notificaciones` y `comentarios` si no usas algún campo para ello o asignas espacio en la primera consulta.

Tu código quedaría:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      echo $row["nombre"];//imrprime nombre de la primera consulta sussccefully
      /* No necesitas esto */
      //echo $row["nombre_e"];//me dice undefined index nombre_e
   }
}
```

Ejemplo reservando espacio:

```
SELECT
  de, para, nombre, apellido, fecha, avatar, post_id,
  null de_e, null para_e, null nombre_e, null apellido_e,
  null fecha_e, null avatar_e, null id_post
FROM comentarios 
WHERE para='$id'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
  de, para, nombre_e, apellido_e, fecha_e, avatar_e, id_post
FROM notificaciones
WHERE para='$id'
ORDER BY GREATEST(fecha, fecha_e) DESC
```

He asignados valores estáticos `null` a los campos `*_e` durante la primera consulta, que serán rellenados por la segunda (y, a su vez, los campos no `*_e` primeros serán rellenados con valores `null`).

He tenido que inventarme el alias `de_e` para el campo `de` de la tabla `notificaciones` para que no haya conflicto de nombres con el campo `de` de la tabla `comentarios`.

Aunque también sería válido y más sencilla la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
  de, para, nombre, apellido, fecha, avatar, post_id, 'comentarios' tabla
FROM comentarios
WHERE para='$id'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  de, para, nombre_e, apellido_e, fecha_e, avatar_e, id_post, 'notificaciones'
FROM notificaciones
WHERE para='$id'
ORDER BY GREATEST(fecha) DESC
```

En la que he creado un campo llamado `tabla` que tendrá el valor `comentarios` o `notificaciones` dependiendo de la tabla a la que pertenezca el registro.

Comment: Sigo sin verle la utilidad.... Sería mucho mas sencillo utilizar un `JOIN`. A ver si contesta con lo que quiere y nos despeja un poco su objetivo.

Comment: Puede tratarse de un sistema de notificaciones en la que sale la típica campana notificando los últimos comentarios o notificaciones, utilidad tiene, pero como tú dices depende del uso que quiera darle. Si es un uso lícito yo propongo soluciones a lo que quiere hacer.

Comment: No me he explicado bien, no me refería a que el tema notificaciones/comentarios no tuviera utilidad, sino una consulta UNION en este caso.

Comment: No me he explicado bien, es posible que esta consulta UNION tenga sentido si quiere unir información de dos tablas con campos similares para mostrarlo en un único listado. Fíjate como está ordenando por el mayor de los campos de fecha, por lo que quiere mostrar los resultados de ambas tablas mezclados, ordenados por fecha independientemente de la tabla de la que provengan los datos.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta  lo que necesito es una consulta que me traiga todo de las dos tablas por eso no uso joins por que no serian necesarios ya que en realidad no nececito hacer ningun match tu respuesta se ve interesante @OscarGarcia provare tu codigo ya te digo como me fue

Comment: Cualquier duda o fallo que pueda dar mi código házmelo saber. Al no disponer de entorno donde reproducir el problema he tenido que hacer los cambios al SQL a ciegas. Te recomiendo especialmente el último ejemplo SQL, es el más limpio (no desperdicia campos y memoria y, además, usa un único campo para diferenciar registros de una u otra tabla si lo necesitas).

Comment: @OscarGarcia he editado mi codigo para que veas los resultados con imagenes de mi problema ojala y puedas ayudarme gracias y perdon por las molestias

Comment: Hola, espero que puedas leer de nuevo los primeros dos párrafos de mi respuesta, en ella está la solución. El resto de la respuesta son mejoras o cambios sugeridos que necesitan adaptarse a tu código exacto. Editaré la respuesta para ponerlo algo más claro.

Comment: gracias por tu edicion y respuesta una pregunta @OscarGarcia concerniente a como leer los datos de la consulta `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      echo $row["nombre"];//imrprime nombre de la primera consulta sussccefully
      /* No necesitas esto */
      //echo $row["nombre_e"];//me dice undefined index nombre_e
   }
}` por que no nececitaria esa linea i mean como leeria entonces las notificaciones de evaluaciones

Comment: vale ya entendi disculpa no estaba entendiendo muy bien ahora si lo arregle ahora @OscarGarcia podrias por favor aclararme otra duda ?

Comment: Claro, ¿Qué duda es?

Comment: ok voy a tratar de ser lo mas claro posible mira para yo  leer en el html la notificacion ya sea de comentarios o evaluacion lo hago de la siguiente manera  ejemplo breve `<div id="notificaciones">notificaciones </div> <div id="comentarios">comentarios</div>` osea estan juntos pero con la mera diferencia que si el usuario evaluo la publicacion el texto es evaluo tu publicacion con  5 etc.. y si comento el texto del div de los comentarios ovio es comento, en fin ya sea que yo comente o evalue me salen los dos juntos evaluo y comento osea dos notificaciones como hago con un if para mostrar si

Comment: comento o evaluo ?

Comment: ya resolvi todo el problemas muchas gracias ahora tengo conceptos claros y dudas aclaradas muchas gracias @OscarGarcia eres genial exitos!!

Comment: Me pillaste comiendo, siento no haber respondido antes. Me alegra haber sido de ayuda :)

Comment: XD saludos @OscarGarcia gracias por tu contribucion a este novato!!